# Using XPath count()

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have simple XML file like that:

```
<screen>
    <object attribute="String"/>
    <object attribute="Relationship">
         <vertices>
             <vertex point_index="1" x="18" y="30" />
             <vertex point_index="2" x="91" y="30" />
             <vertex point_index="3" x="91" y="60" />
             <vertex point_index="4" x="18" y="60" />                   
         </vertices>
    </object>
</screen>
```

How to correctly use XPath(1.0) count() function to receive vertices count in object with specified type? I'm trying to use the following string, but online XPath test tool (http://www.xpathtester.com/test) returns error.

```
count(/screen/object[@attribute="Relationship"]/vertices/*)
```

What seems to be wrong?

Comment: vard, You may be interested to try the XPath Visualizer -- an open source and non-commercial tool written by me. During the years the XPath Visualizer has helped thousands of people learn XPath the fun way. http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the XPath. It is just that the testing tool you are using is not able to return number as result. Try this testing tool instead: http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm

Comment: Yeah, your tool said it's correct. Seems like most online XPath test tools aren't able to parse same XPath.